# Does Crawling Eye grant line-of-effect across Impenetrable Barrier?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, warlock, line-of-effect

I was trying to think of really fun, evil things to do with a warlock. I was curious if this works:

1. Use Crawling Eye
2. Use Impenetrable Barrier between you and the eye
3. Do horrible things to opponents such as: Word of Changing, Wall of Perilous Flame, Painful Slumber of Ages, Tenacious Plague, Chilling Tentacles, etc. Basically anything that doesn't require a ray from your hands.

Would that work, or is line-of-effect still broken by the wall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lesser invocation *crawling eye* says, "You can't cast most invocations or spells through the eye" (*Complete Mage* 123). The dark invocation *impenetrable barrier* allows the warlock to "conjure a *wall of force* as the spell" (*Dragon Magic* 82).

A [*wall of force*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/wallOfForce.htm) blocks line of effect despite it not blocking line of sight. Further, since effects can't *start from* the crawling eye, the warlock himself typically must still have line of sight to his foe to employ many effects against that foe.